# type of expression is ambiguous without more context - in Facebook wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift3

I am new on Swift and iOS and there is something interesting happening here.

In my `ViewController` I am using this code and its working great.

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()


loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .email ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
    switch loginResult {
    case .failed(let error):
        print(error)
    case .cancelled:
        print("User cancelled login.")
    case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
        print("Logged in!\(accessToken)")
    }
}
```

When I am putting it in the other class such as `LoginService` I got an error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Here is the funkction on LoginService class

```
  func doFaceBookLogin(viewController: UIViewController?) {
        let loginManager = LoginManager()

        loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .email ], viewController) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in!\(accessToken)")
            }
        }
    }
```

What I did wrong here?

Comment: Which line is showing the error?

Comment: in the line loginManager.logIn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your second method call is you forgot to mention second parameter label `viewController` with your `logIn` method.

```
loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .email ], viewController: viewController) { loginResult in

}
```

Comment: @pmb Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 4):

you should write it like this. It works for me..

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self) { (loginResult) in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4 and xCode version Version 9.2 this will work:

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile, .email ], viewController: self, completion: { (loginResult) in

})
```